# Direct logging to different outputfiles with log4net

Tags: logging, castle-windsor, log4net

I need to log certain events in my app to a certain file. I have a main log file which is working, but how do I direct specific events to a certain file.

In my example below, how do i log the count property to a certain file?

```
ILogger mainApplog = container.Resolve<ILogger>(); // this is working just fine to c:\log.txt
ILogger valuesLog = container.Resolve<ILogger>(); // what should I resolve to log to c:\values.txt?

mainApplog.DebugFormat("Calculating values");

var count = 0;
while (true)
{

    count++;
    valuesLog.InfoFormat(count.ToString());


    if (count > 100)
        break;
}
mainApplog.DebugFormat("Calculations completed");
```

Comment: In general you should not directly resolve component, except your top level component. For logging component, usually the logging facility is used (http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Logging-Facility.ashx). If you choose to use this every component will get it's own logger and you can configure log4net to send output of different components to different files.

Comment: I agree, but I "feels" unnessecary to build my own logging framework when already using log4net to accomplish almost the same thing. But do you know how i can direct certain output based on purpose (in opposite to component)?

Comment: The ILogger that you are referering to, would that be ILogger from windosr or ILogger from Log4Net ?

Comment: Log4Net (actually through Castle Windsor) but Windsor doesn't really matter, I'd like to know how to do it with Log4net.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only about Log4Net try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>

  <log4net>
    <appender name="MainAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender" >
      <mapping>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <foreColor value="White" />
        <backColor value="Red, HighIntensity" />
      </mapping>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
        <LoggerToMatch value="MainApplicationLog" />
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter">
      </filter>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ValueAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender" >
      <mapping>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <foreColor value="White" />
        <backColor value="Green, HighIntensity" />
      </mapping>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
        <LoggerToMatch value="ValuesLog" />
      </filter>
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter">
      </filter>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="MainAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="ValueAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

You can replace the appender with a choice of your own. For completeness, this is the code that will do the logging.

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

ILog mainAppLog = LogManager.GetLogger("MainApplicationLog");
ILog valuesLog = LogManager.GetLogger("ValuesLog");

mainAppLog.Debug("Calculating values");
valuesLog.InfoFormat("{0}", 0); // do not use ToString, you will use processor time even when not logging
```